# Знаки препинания в стихотворении

Tags: пунктуация, поэзия

Боль в душе.

Всему есть придел
Но я не знав эту грань
Влюбился ранив душу
Душа бьется за любовь
Выскакивая из груди
Душа плачет ревет.
Делает больно всему
Кровь льется из сердца в душу
Душа плачет, ей невыносима трудно
Не хватает силы дышать
Она постепенна начала умирать!

Comment: пожалуйста помогите

Comment: поставьте знаки препинание, это стих

Answer (score 4):

Рассматриваю только пунктуацию и орфографию.

1. "Боль в душе" — это заголовок, точка в конце не ставится.
2. "Придел" — правильно **предел** (ограничение, граница, черта; *предел мечтаний, на пределе сил*). Пр**и**дел — часть храма (особый алтарь, отдельный от главного).
3. *Не зна**я** эту грань, ранив душу, выскакивая из груди* — деепричастные обороты, обычно выделяются запятыми.
4. "Невыносима" — наречие (как?), правильно **невыносимо**.
5. "Постепенна" — наречие (как?), правильно **постепенно**.
6. "Не хватает силы" — обычно используется **не хватает сил** (изо всех сил, из последних сил).

**Боль в душе**

*Всему есть предел!

Но я, — не зная эту грань, —

Влюбился, ранив душу.

Душа бьется за любовь,

Выскакивая из груди,

Душа плачет, ревет,

Делает больно всему.*
*Кровь льется из сердца в душу —

Душа плачет, ей невыносимо трудно,

Не хватает силы дышать!

Она постепенно начала умирать...*

Comment: «...постепенно начала умирать»? А начали с того, что рассматривается только пунктуация и орфография.